# How to exclude the Overlapping records/time in Excel

Tags: sql, excel

Is there any build in function or a ways to exclude the overlapping records in Excel directly. Specifically, based on timestamp. Please refer the following example. Row 2 and 4 (in Example) are overlapping, I am trying to exclude the overlapping records. I tried by using the rank function to exclude the duplicates but I was un-able to exclude it.

**Example:**

```
  S.NO  SQ  Date    [Start Time]    [End Time]
    1   1   1/9/2015    18:00        23:55
    1   1   1/9/2015    19:00        22:55
    1   2   1/9/2015    19:00        23:59
    1   2   1/9/2015    19:00        21:59
```

**Expected Output:**

```
  S.NO  SQ  Date    [Start Time][End Time]  Expected Out put    Comments
    1   1   1/9/2015    18:00   23:55       5.92     
    1   1   1/9/2015    19:00   22:55       0                   Exclude this record
    1   2   1/9/2015    19:00   23:59       4.98     
    1   2   1/9/2015    19:00   21:59       0                   Exclude this record
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data sample provided seems may not cover all the relevant possibilities, interpreting 'overlap' as being wholly within (discounting the boundaries), assuming that `S.NO` is in A1 that only adjacent entries need be considered, then:

```
 =24*IF(ROW()=2,E2-D2,IF(AND(C2+D2>=C1+D1,C2+E2<=C1+E1),0,(E2-D2)))
```

in F2 and copied down to suit and with ColumnF formatted:

```
0.00;;0
```

and left justified, and with:

```
=IF(F2>0,"","Exclude this record")
```

in G2 and copied down to suit produces:

[image]

once the labels have been filled in F1 and G1.

Answer (score 0):

Make the datarange an excel table: In the example `Table1`.
In a new column in the table, enter the following formula, using the new `FILTER` command in Excel365:

`=CHOOSECOLS(FILTER(Table1[[S.No]:[EndTime]],([Date]=[@Date])*([StartTime]<[ @EndTime ])*([EndTime]>[@StartTime]),""),2)`

If the formula results in more than 1 record, this formula will result in a `#Spill!` error (error code 9). This can then be used for subsequent processing, like conditional formatting.

Please note: No spaces allowed in ColumnNames in the Table; in the Filter Array exclude the new column in the table, otherwise a circular reference occurs. More conditions can be added if needed to the result in a unique record. The multiplication symbol `*` indicates an AND condition. The `CHOOSECOLS` is used to prevent spill errors if any data are in columns to the right.

If the new column is outside of the table, the last row may result in multiple rows answer, not a spill error.
If not all used column cells in a row are filled, a `#value` error results.